# How to get forecast results on training data?

Tags: python, deep-learning, lstm

I have a Long Short-Term Memory (LSTM) deep neural network code that makes multivariate forecasts of a variable, The database is split into a training and test set:

```
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, Dropout

model=Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units=50,return_sequences=True, input_shape=(1,5)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(units=50))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')

model.fit(X_train_shape,y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=48)
```

The database is split into a training and test set.

As final results the model gives me the forecast results on the test data set.
How can I get the prediction results of the training data as well?

Comment: Check the keras documentation on [the sequential model](https://keras.io/guides/sequential_model/). You can use it as `y = model(x)`.

Comment: How do you split data to train and test? Are you sure, Your model is trained on data, and those data here on test and you don't evaluate the model on test data that you don't see in training phase?